# Need to detect Sunday in JS Date and show accordingly in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to show weekdays and date that is 1 day ahead up to 4 days.
Idea is currentDay+1, currentDay+2, currentDay+3, currentDay+4.
So if currentDay is Wednesday the array should be Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday.
However, I get empty in place of Sunday.

[`fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/moinchoudhari/2e10tp9q/)

```js
$(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sa"];
  $('.plus1').text(d.getDate() + 1);
  $('.plus2').text(d.getDate() + 2);
  $('.plus3').text(d.getDate() + 3);
  $('.plus4').text(d.getDate() + 4);
  $('.day1').text(days[d.getDay() + 1]);
  $('.day2').text(days[d.getDay() + 2]);
  $('.day3').text(days[d.getDay() + 3]);
  $('.day4').text(days[d.getDay() + 4]);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="day1">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus1"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="day2">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus2"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="day3">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus3"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="day4">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus4"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because when you do this:

```
  $('.day4').text(days[d.getDay() + 4]);
```

there is a chance that you exceed the size of the array. So, instead use this:

```
  $('.day4').text(days[(d.getDay() + 4) % 7]);
```

See demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sa"];
  $('.plus1').text(d.getDate() + 1);
  $('.plus2').text(d.getDate() + 2);
  $('.plus3').text(d.getDate() + 3);
  $('.plus4').text(d.getDate() + 4);
  $('.day1').text(days[(d.getDay() + 1) % 7]);
  $('.day2').text(days[(d.getDay() + 2) % 7]);
  $('.day3').text(days[(d.getDay() + 3) % 7]);
  $('.day4').text(days[(d.getDay() + 4) % 7]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="day1">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus1"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="day2">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus2"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="day3">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus3"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="day4">Today</span>&nbsp;<span class="plus4"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Moin good to know it helped :) also accept the answer and upvote, thanks!

Comment: any idea adding current month? I tried this but blank output.

Comment: var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
 $('.month').text(months[d.getMonth()]);